# Topological sort for a grid of arbitrary points?

Tags: algorithm, graph, grid, topological-sort

I have a grid of points x,y where you can move from one point to an immediately visible point as long as the new point has either a greater x, y, or both. How would I sort this topologically?

Comment: Why can't you just take the [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Algorithms) algorithm, and adapt it for your particulars?

Comment: Trying to understanding how to adapt it. All I have is array of points x,y

Comment: Ok, which part is causing you the problem?

Comment: Determining connected points, the proper data structure for it, what the end result should look like in my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a transitive relation (i.e. if you can go from a to b, and b to c, then you must be able to go from a to c) you can simply sort your points to achieve a topological ordering.

For example, this C code would perform a topological sort of an array of points by ordering the points based on the first coordinate, or by the second coordinate if the first coordinate matches.

```
int C[1000][2];

int compar(const void*a,const void*b)
{
  int *a2=(int*)a;
  int *b2=(int*)b;
  int d=a2[0]-b2[0];
  if (d)
    return d;  // Sort on first coordinate
  return a2[1]-b2[1];  // Sort on second coordinate
}

...
qsort(C,1000,sizeof(int)*2,compar);
...
```

For your example  (0,0) (1,99) (9,16) (16,9) (36,64) (64,36) (100,100), these points are already sorted according to the first coordinate so this would be the output of the call to qsort.

This approach works because if you can go from a to b, then a must either have a smaller x (and so appears earlier in the list), or the same x and a smaller y (and again appears earlier in the sorted list).

Comment: If I have to pass b on the way from a to c then I cannot say I can go from a to c directly

Comment: You are right.  I misread the question as requiring **both** x and y to be greater than or equal.  However, if this is not the correct reading then it is impossible to have a topological sort because you can go from (9,16) to (16,9) (greater x) and (16,9) to (9,16) (greater y) and so the graph contains cycles.

Answer (score 2):

There are a huge number of topological orderings of this grid.  However, some of them are very easy to compute without any space overhead:

1. Iterate across the rows from bottom-to-top, left to right.
2. Iterate across the columns from left to right, bottom to top.
3. List all points whose sum of x and y is zero, then whose sum of x and y is 1, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So what if I had points (0,0) (1,99) (9,16) (16,9) (36,64) (64,36) (100,100) ?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian- Oh, my apologies - I misinterpreted your question.  I thought you had an n x m grid of all points in a rectangle, not an explicit list of all the points you need to consider.  I would suggest updating your question to make this clearer - a "grid of points" usually implies a complete rectangle.